# Programmatically changing the TabView focus

Tags: swiftui, tabview

I have a SwiftUI TabView that calls 5 separate views: Location, Calculate etc.

[image]

These work perfectly. But some views are called programmatically within the App. So, for example, when you have chosen your Location you move to the Calculate view. When I do this how would I programatically tell it to move the TabView focus onto the Calculate icon from the CalculateView?

I have a separate MenuView that controls the Tabs:

```
struct MenuView: View {
    
    @State public var selectedTab = Tab.location  // was private
    
    public enum Tab: Hashable {
            case location
            case calculate
            case install
            case results
            case about
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                LocationView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Location", systemImage: "globe.europe.africa")
                    }
                    .tag(Tab.location)
                CalculateView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Calculate", systemImage: "apps.ipad")
                    }
                    .tag(Tab.calculate)
                InstallView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Install", systemImage: "window.ceiling.closed")
                    }
                    .tag(Tab.install)
                ResultsView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Results", systemImage: "sun.max.fill")
                    }
                    .tag(Tab.results)
                AboutView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("About", systemImage: "gear")
                    }
                    .tag(Tab.about)
            } // TabView
            .accentColor(.yellow)                                               //Active tab color
            .background(Color.white)
        }                                                                       // VStack
    }                                                                               // body
    
    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.systemGray //TabBar color
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.red //systemGray
        UITabBar.appearance().isOpaque = false
    }
}
```

Comment: just pass the `selectedTab` as a binding to the tab views, and in these other views, declare
 `@Binding var selectedTab: Tab` and change the value in there. Note, you would need
 to put the `enum Tab` outside the `MenuView` so all views can access it.

Comment: not relevant to your question, but if you have five tabs, doesn't that mean that the user can click any tab, any time? So, even if they haven't selected a location, yet, they could click on Calculate..... my understanding is that tabs are intended to be used to display separate, distinct things, not as multiple steps in a single process. 

you may want to rethink/refactor the flow in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the `selectedTab` as a binding to the tab views, and in these views, declare
`@Binding var selectedTab: Tab` and change the value in there.

Here is a working example code, that outlines the approach:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MenuView()
    }
}

struct CalculateView: View {
    @Binding var selectedTab: Tab
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("click me CalculateView", action: {selectedTab = Tab.install} )
    }
}

struct LocationView: View {
    @Binding var selectedTab: Tab
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("click me LocationView", action: {selectedTab = Tab.calculate} )
    }
}

struct InstallView: View {
    @Binding var selectedTab: Tab
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("click me InstallView", action: {selectedTab = Tab.location} )
    }
}

public enum Tab: Hashable {
        case location
        case calculate
        case install
        case results
        case about
}

struct MenuView: View {
    
    @State var selectedTab = Tab.location

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                LocationView(selectedTab: $selectedTab)  // <-- here
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Location", systemImage: "globe.europe.africa")
                    }
                    .tag(Tab.location)
                CalculateView(selectedTab: $selectedTab)
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Calculate", systemImage: "apps.ipad")
                    }
                    .tag(Tab.calculate)
                InstallView(selectedTab: $selectedTab)
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Install", systemImage: "window.ceiling.closed")
                    }
                    .tag(Tab.install)
//                ResultsView()
//                    .tabItem {
//                        Label("Results", systemImage: "sun.max.fill")
//                    }
//                    .tag(Tab.results)
//                AboutView()
//                    .tabItem {
//                        Label("About", systemImage: "gear")
//                    }
//                    .tag(Tab.about)
            } // TabView
            .accentColor(.yellow)
            .background(Color.white)
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.systemGray //TabBar color
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.red //systemGray
        UITabBar.appearance().isOpaque = false
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that before and got some Scope issues I couldn't resolve. I'll follow your advice and try again. Many thanks.

Comment: All my Views are separate Views and not in the same one as per your example. This approach wants me to put a binding in the preview along the lines of LocationView(selectedTab: $selectedTab). This gives a cannot fine $selectedTab in scope error even with the @Binding var selectedTab: Tab.

Comment: My example code follows from your question code. All the views are seperate views.
If you have other code that you are not showing but is relevant,
 then it is not possible to guess what you are wanting to do. Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then we can try to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Create a router class

```
import Foundation

final class NavigationRouter: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedTabIndex = 0
}

enum TabIndex: Int {
    case home = 0
    case details = 1
    case settings = 2
}
```

Step 2, create your TabBar

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyTabView: View {

    @State var router = NavigationRouter()

    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $router.selectedTabIndex) {
            
            HomeScreen(router: router)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Menu", systemImage: "list.dash")
                }
            
            DetailScreen(router: router)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Order", systemImage: "square.and.pencil")
                }

            MySettingsScreen(router: router)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Settings", systemImage: "arrow.down.app.fill")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Step 3. use a button in any of your view to navigate

```
struct HomeScreen: View {
    let router: NavigationRouter
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("To Settings") {
            router.selectedTabIndex = TabIndex.settings.rawValue
        }
    }
}
```